# Date Format Issue With DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-time, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

I have a date in the following format: `1/1/2020 3:4:7 AM` I am trying to format it using `DateTimeFormatter`.

I have the following code with a formatter to parse it, but it doesn't work.

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("1/1/2020 3:4:7 AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"));
```

I get the following exception:

> `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1/1/2020 3:4:7 AM' could not be parsed at index 0`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to use `"M/d/uuuu h:m:s a"` as format pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two separate problems:

### Wrong counts

You're using e.g. `MM` which is an explicit: Always the full amount of digits, zero-padded. Your string is not like that, it's just the number. So, make that `M/d/uuuu h:m:s a`.

EDIT: Changed `yyyy` to `uuuu`, thanks, @deHaar. Reasoning: yyyy or uuuu rarely matters, but note that this mean 4 digits are *required*. The difference kicks in for years before 0: `uuuu` goes negative, `yyyy` does not and expects you to use e.g. `GG` so that you get `44 BC` instead of `-44`. In that way, `uuuu` is just more correct, even though usually the difference is not going to come up.

### Missing locale

The second problem is that you should pretty much **never** use this version of `ofPattern` - it has a bug, which you can't catch with unit tests, which makes that a bug that is thousands of times 'heavier', and thus, a real problem.

You need to specify locale. Without it, 'AM' is not going to parse unless your platform default locale is english.

### Putting it together

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("1/1/2020 3:4:7 AM",
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu h:m:s a", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

works great.

Comment: Thank you, I am marking your answer as accepted as you pointed out that Local.ENGLISH was also required.

Comment: I would use `uuuu` for the year (of no specific era), otherwise this answer got a well-deserved accept...

Answer (score 4):

1. Use single letters for date and time components (month, day, year, hour, minute, and second).
2. You can also make the formatter handle the pattern in a case insensitive way (e.g. am, AM, Am) as shown below:

   ```
   import java.time.LocalDateTime;
   import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
   import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
   import java.util.Locale;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Formatter to handle the pattern in case insensitive way (e.g. am, AM, Am)
           DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                               .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                               .appendPattern("M/d/u h:m:s a")
                                               .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
           LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("1/1/2020 3:4:7 AM", formatter);
           System.out.println(date);
       }
   }
   ```

**Output:**

```
2020-01-01T03:04:07
```

Comment: Just great someone introduces a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` here ;-)

Answer (score 4):

In your snippet:

```java
LocalDateTime
    .parse("1/1/2020 3:4:7 AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"));
```

- `1` - does not match `MM`
- `1` - does not match `dd`
- `3`  - does not match `hh`
- `4`  - does not match `mm`
- `7`  - does not match `ss`

i.e. the lengths of the *formatter pattern* parts (e.g. `MM`) and their respective parts from the *string text* (e.g. `1`) do not match.

You can match them in a few ways, e.g. you can either change the *string text* to match the *formatter pattern* or other way around.

You can try this instead:

```java
LocalDateTime
    .parse("01/01/2020 03:04:07 AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"));
```

Additionally, have a look at the [Pattern Letters and Symbols](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation of DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> **Number:** If the count of letters is **one**, then the value is output using the **minimum number of digits** and without padding. Otherwise, the count of digits is used as the width of the output field, with the value zero-padded as necessary.

By reversing the reasoning, you can try using this formatter instead:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy h:m:s a")
```